# IE8, IE9, IE10 Blinking Cursor Issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, contenteditable, text-cursor

I am making an editor which shows a toolbar on some text selection. The issue that I am facing in IE is that the blinking cursor still shows above the toolbar.
This is specifically happening in IE. The blinking cursor comes on top.

Here is the sample for this issue:

```js
$('.content').mouseup(function(e) {
  $('.shy').css({
    top: e.pageY - 30 + 'px',
    left: e.pageX - 30 + 'px'
  });
  $('.shy').show();
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 1;
}
.shy {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class='content'>Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content</div>
<div class='shy'>
  <div>
```

Taking the focus out is not an option as there are more components in this application and this fix will not work for those situations. The fix needs to be completely autonomous.

Comment: If you can't manipulate the focus, then you might be out of luck since it seems the cursor is controlled natively by the browser, as pointed out in [this example](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1597485)

Comment: @ZachEsposito :Yes, focus seems like the only option but really bad option. This means I'd have to make the fix in every other component that comes above the contenteditable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
$('.shy').focus();
```

And cursor will stop blinking on IE7-IE10 (tested)

http://jsfiddle.net/2QAxk/6/

**UDP1**
Sorry didn't see your update about 'focus' not been an option...